# Placing randomly sized objects side by side unity 2D

Tags: unity-game-engine, coordinates, bounds

I am attempting to instantiate differently shaped prefabs next to eachother. I have a folder full of differently sized objects that allow for me to string them together randomly to create a 2D endless runner. My issue is that all the answers online about placing objects beside eachother don't work when different sized objects are used. Here is the code I am using to instantiate the sections. It works when it only randomly selects similar sized objects. When the selected prefab is a different length it leaves either a gap between, or overlaps, the previous object.

```
  for(int i = 0; i < activeSectionsAtOnce; i++)
    {
        int index = Random.Range(0, sectionPrefabs.Length);
        GameObject currentOb = sectionPrefabs[index];

        Vector2 position = new Vector2();
        if(activeSections.Count == 0)
        {
            //set a (0, 0) position for first object
            position = Vector2.zero;
        }
        else
        {
            //get most recently placed object from list
            GameObject lastOb = activeSections[activeSections.Count - 1];

            //my attempt at getting bounds for the last object and for the next prefab that will be used
            Bounds lasObbounds = new Bounds(lastOb.transform.position, Vector2.zero);
            Bounds currentBounds = new Bounds(currentOb.transform.position, Vector2.zero);

            //Include child objects(all have sprite renderers)
            foreach (Renderer r in lastOb.GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>())
            {
                lasObbounds.Encapsulate(r.bounds);
            }
            foreach (Renderer rend in currentOb.GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>())
            {
                currentBounds.Encapsulate(rend.bounds);
            }
            //position object will be instantiated at
            position.x = lastOb.transform.position.x + (lasObbounds.size.x / 2) + (currentBounds.size.x/2);
        }
        //instantiate at selected position
        activeSections.Add(
            Instantiate(currentOb, position, Quaternion.identity)
        );
    }
```

This is in the start method. I'm not sure if the problem is how I'm creating the bounds, or how im mathematicaly creating the x coordinate. This is the expected result that happens when I use same sized prefabs. [image: this is the expected output] This is what happens with different prefabs [image: result]
The shorter protrusion from the first object should be cleanly between the other two without a gap.

Here's an image of one prefab
[image: prefab]

Thanks for any advice

Comment: What's your expected result? can you please attach an image? If you have the same size issue, I can suggest you set all prefab's scale and boundaries to what you want and just instantiate them at runtime.

Comment: @MohammadRezaArashiyan I added images in an edit

Comment: If you place bounding boxes around the prefabs then before you are ready to instantiate the next one check the bounding box of the previous one and the one you are about to place and put them together accordingly. Bounding box right-side against bounding box left-side.  ( or vice-versa, however you look at it )

Comment: @jiveturkey does moving the bounds of the prefab change the location of the prefab in game? If so would it have the same effect? The bounding box is not attached to the prefabs parent, it is a collection of the childrens bounds.

Comment: Not really sure what that last sentence means but moving the box does not move the prefab.  If you make the Bounding Box a property, it will move when the prefab is moved.  There are many Q&A's about wrapping an object in a box, etc.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not quite sure what you mean for me to do.